# Exception's ToString() method

Tags: c#, resharper, tostring

I found in someones code following :

```
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
}
```

Resharper is graying out the `ToString()` call which is as always a great suggestion.
How does this C# code work without it ? Will `ToString()` be called implicitly ?

Comment: You are not showing the relevant code.

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with it. If it is used in string.Format(0 or string concatenation - then yes, of course

Comment: -1 for now: Please post actual code/simplified by compilable code.

Comment: I didn't think it would make a difference at first.

Comment: taking -1 back - now have code clearly showing the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the exception is being used within a string... For example `"something" + exception.ToString()` or `String.Format("... {0}", exception)`, then yes, `ToString` will be called without you having to call it explicitly.

And... as you updated your example, calling `Console.WriteLine()` against any object value, `ToString` will be called. [Here's the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx), with as much detail as you could possibly want.

Answer (score 7):

[Console.WriteLine has an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/swx4tc5e.aspx) that takes an object. This object's `ToString` method is called internally so there's no need for you to add `ToString` in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the something is string concatenation or used as a parameter in a formatted string, then yes, `ToString` is called implicitly.

**UPDATE FOLLOWING QUESTION UPDATE**

Console has an overload of WriteLine that accepts an `object` argument, in this version on the method ToString is called if the passed instance is not null - R# is aware of this and suggests the choice of the preferable overload.